# Django - setting up urls.py and views.py

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm new to Django and am trying to configure my urls.py and views.py docs. This is probably a very simple issue but I can't for the life of me set up my urls.py and views.py docs so that localhost/index points to an index.html file I have created. I have followed the Django Project tutorial to the letter and tried many, many variations but this just isn't clicking for me. Any help would be much appreciated!

The index.html file is located at mysite/templates/index.html

My folder structure is like this...

```
 mysite/
      mysite/
           __init__.py
           settings.py
           urls.py
           wsgi.py
      app/
           __init__.py
           admin.py
           models.py
           tests.py
           urls.py
           views.py
      templates/
           css
           img
           js
           index.html
```

My views.py contains:

```
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
 from django.template import Context, loader
 from django.http import Http404

 def index(request):
     return render(request, "templates/index.html")
```

UPDATE: My folder structure now looks like this:

```
 mysite/
      mysite/
           __init__.py
           settings.py
           urls.py
           wsgi.py
           templates/
                     index.html
      app/
           __init__.py
           admin.py
           models.py
           tests.py
           urls.py
           views.py
      static/
           css
           img     
           js
```

Comment: It would help if you showed your `views.py`, or at least the relevant bits.

Comment: @Noio Thanks Noio. I've added it to the question.

Comment: Have you added your application in settings.py in the INSTALLED_APPS list?

Comment: @SteveMayne Hi Steve, yes I've added both mysite and app to cover all angles.

Comment: You say "The index.html file is located at mysite/templates/index.html" but your folder structure suggests otherwise.

Comment: @SteveMayne Does it? My parent folder is called mysite and the templates folder sits inside that with the index.html file within it. I may have this wrong - could you please elaborate.

Comment: Looks correct to me, perhaps it's the two mysite folders that threw Steve.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake - guilty as charged.  Sorry @PirateKitten and Jess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you defined the template path in `TEMPLATE_DIRS`.

settings.py

```
# at start add this
import os, sys

abspath = lambda *p: os.path.abspath(os.path.join(*p))

PROJECT_ROOT = abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_ROOT)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    abspath(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'), # this will point to mysite/mysite/templates
)
```

Then move your templates folder to `mysite > mysite > templates`

Then instead of `return render(request, "templates/index.html")` just do like this `return render(request, "index.html")`. This should work.

Your directory structure should be:

```
mysite/
      mysite/
          __init__.py
          settings.py
          urls.py
          wsgi.py

          templates/
              index.html
          static/
              css/
              js/
          app/
               __init__.py
               admin.py
               models.py
               tests.py
               urls.py
               views.py
```

Answer (score 3):

On top of setting up your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in `settings.py`:

```
import os

ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (    
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'templates'),
)
```

#### mysite/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', include('app.urls', namespace='app'), name='app'),
)
```

#### app/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('app.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index', name='index'),
)
```

In your `views.py` code as is, change `templates/index.html` to `index.html` and the template should go under:

```
mysite/mysite/templates/index.html
```

On another note, your `css`, `js` and `img` folders are best placed somewhere else like a `mysite/static` folder.

Comment: Thanks Thierry. I have done the above and restarted the development server but am seeing the below error. Any ideas? 
_"TemplateDoesNotExist at /
templates/index.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value: 
templates/index.html"_

Comment: @Jess can you show me what your project/app structure looks like now?

Comment: @Jess Actually, change your view `templates/index.html` to `index.html`

Comment: I've just added my updated folder structure to the question above. Thought it would be easier than in a comment. Should I remove the templates folder and have index.html sitting in the mysite/mysite/ folder?

Comment: In `app/views.py`, change `templates/index.html` to `index.html` and it should work

Comment: It works!! Thank you! The index.html page seems to have lost its styling - I'm using Twitter Bootstrap. Do you know where I need to store the Bootstrap files for the styling to return to the index page?

Comment: Read from the following two sections https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/.  There's a learning curve, try it, play with it and you can post a new question on SO on what you have tried so far and we can help you further if it's not working.